# Whitelabel Error on a simple Hello World app spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I try to go `localhost:8080/` I got `whitelabel error`.

My Controller:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FormController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

I tried using different ports too.

**My dependencies:**
Spring Web,
Spring Web Services,
Jersey,
Spring Data JPA and H2 database.

I am about to lose it so please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**:

```
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
```

**Long answer:**

Without `@ResponseBody` because you have `@Controller` and Spring-Mvc, it will try to use the String that you return `"Hello World!"` and match it with a jsp view that is named `"Hello World!"` which obviously does not exist and therefore you get the whitelabel error.

Adding `@ResponseBody` Spring-Mvc will not try to find a view with this name but will return just this simple response as String.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also tried adding .jsp file as well (return hello.jsp). But it did not work too. Any idea why?

Comment: I can edit the question for more details if you are willing to help me.

Comment: Search some online tutorial you will see some other small configurations needed to serve the jsp

Comment: Thank you currently I am doing that and the problem is solved by itself... Can you recommend me any tutorial, video etc. for working spring boot?